# Enforce Uniqueness on a Subset of Rows on Table in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger, database-indexes

For a table, CARS, with two columns, MAKE and MODEL, I would like to enforce that that for some particular MAKE values, their MODEL values must be unique (assuming this is an Oracle database).

For example, I want to enforce duplicates for Ford, but not Toyota. I do not want more than one row with the 'F150' MODEL and the 'Ford' MAKE. However, it is okay to have two rows with the 'Rav4' MODEL and the 'Toyota' MAKE.  It is also okay to have a row with the 'F150' MODEL and the 'Ford' MAKE and another row with the 'F150' MODEL and the 'Toyota' MAKE.

I have been researching various strategies with triggers, constraints, or indexes, but I have not found anything yet that would give me the level of control that I need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a unique function-based index to enforce uniqueness of (make,model) pairs only when make='Ford':

```
create table cars (make varchar2(255) not null, model varchar2(255) not null);

create unique index ford_index on cars (
  case make 
  when 'Ford' then make
  else null
  end,
  case make 
  when 'Ford' then model
  else null
  end  );


insert into cars (make, model) values ('Ford', 'F150');
insert into cars (make, model) values ('Ford', 'Fiesta');
insert into cars (make, model) values ('Toyota', 'Camry');
insert into cars (make, model) values ('Toyota', 'Camry');
insert into cars (make, model) values ('Ford', 'F150'); --- FAILS with unique constraint violation
```

ford_index indexes (make, model) only if make='Ford' - everything else is left out of the index and so is not subject to the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: How would you write this, though, if there are twenty-eight makes for which uniqueness must be enforced, and thirty-six others for which uniqueness is not needed? How would it be maintained if the list of makes that require uniqueness changes over time?

Comment: @mathguy - probably I would create one index for each make that requires model uniqueness.  Since we're talking about car manufacturers I expect the number of makes would be reasonably low.

Comment: Thanks!  I had not thought of using case-statements in this situation. This is certainly the best way I have seen.  

Unfortunately for me, I have to add this to an existing table that already has duplicates (to prevent future dups) but there does not appear to be any index equivalent for the 'DEFFERED NOVALIDATE' options you can give on a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Create a materialized view, with fast refresh on commit. The MV definition may be simply `select make, model from <your_table> where make in (select make from <small_table>)`. The `<small_table>` will list the makes for which you want to enforce this uniqueness. And then create a unique index on `(make, model)` in the materialized view.

Whenever a duplication is attempted with the make `'Ford'`, the MV will be refreshed on commit. The change in the MV will be rejected, which in turn will cause the original `COMMIT` to fail.

Comment: it would be fine if you add the create statement to your post.

Comment: @miracle173 - the create materialized view statement is trivial. More importantly, the MV log(s) must be created first.

Comment: Fast refreshable mviews cannot have a select list subquery.

Comment: @eaolson - That is correct, and it is irrelevant to what I posted. A "select list subquery" is a subquery **in the `SELECT` clause** of a query. I have no such thing in my solution.

Comment: @eaolson Here is the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DWHSG/basic-materialized-views.htm#GUID-505C24CF-5D56-4820-88AA-2221410950E7) I can't find this restriction

Comment: I see a -1 vote. A reason for it (what is wrong with this solution) would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @miracle173 - the restriction is in the documentation - it is just IRRELEVANT. eaolson is confused about the meaning of SELECT LIST subquery.

Comment: @mathguy so the restriction is not in the documention

Comment: @miracle173 The restriction **is** in the documentation, but I do not have a subquery in the `SELECT` clause of the materialized view. That would be something like `select make, model, (select something from somewhere) as some_alias from table1 ...` etc. I have no such thing in my MV.

Comment: I don't agree with with you but I won't continue this discussion.